# How to animate a view on button click iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

With the following code I'm showing a view with an animation on a button click.

```
UIViewController *modalView = self.pageViewController;

[self.view addSubview:modalView.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    CGRect currentRect = modalView.view.frame;
    currentRect.origin.y = 650.0f;
    currentRect.size.height = 295.0f;
    [modalView.view setFrame:currentRect];
    [modalView.view removeFromSuperview];

}];

[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This works fine for first time button click. When I'm pressing the button again and again this is not animating anymore. It's animating for the first time only. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is really not the way to do it. You shouldn't add another viewcontrollers view as a subview to another viewcontroller, it breaks the mvc pattern. Dive in to UIViewControllerTransisitions instead, here's a good tutorial: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that modalView.view's frame initially if different from

```
currentRect.origin.y = 650.0f;
currentRect.size.height = 295.0f;
```

so when changes its frame animation is happens.
But next time when you perform button's action modalView.view's current frame and that frame you sets are same. So there is nothing to animate at all.
Also, you should move `[modalView.view removeFromSuperview];` from animation block to completion block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    CGRect currentRect = modalView.view.frame;
    currentRect.origin.y = 650.0f;
    currentRect.size.height = 295.0f;
    [modalView.view setFrame:currentRect];} 
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [modalView.view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```